# Cannot get login button positioned correctly in navbar

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

The button that is labelled "Login" needs to be pushed to the right of the navbar and lined up properly with other buttons. Here is a jfiddle to see what it's doing. I am using bootstrap to design this and am having trouble with positioning of certain buttons.
 https://jsfiddle.net/sterlingmd17/tk17zjfq/1/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="{{a}}"> <a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="{{b}}"> <a href="#order">Order form</a></li>
            <li class="{{c}}"> <a href="#about">About Swirlz</a></li>
            <li class="{{d}}"> <a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <!--TODO fix login button positioning -->
            <div class="btn-group dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Login
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"></div>
          </div>
          </ul>

        </div>

    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, move the button div outside of the unordered list tags, then add the classes `navbar-form` and `navbar-right` to the button div.

It should look like this

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="{{a}}"> <a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="{{b}}"> <a href="#order">Order form</a></li>
    <li class="{{c}}"> <a href="#about">About Swirlz</a></li>
    <li class="{{d}}"> <a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!--TODO fix login button positioning -->
  <div class="navbar-form navbar-right btn-group dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Login
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```